# How can you keep track of revisions in a csv file with a Python program?

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file where each row has an ID followed by several attributes. Initially, my task was to find the IDs with matching attributes and put them together as a family. Then, outputting them in another CSV document under the format of every relationship printed in different rows.

The basic outline for the CSV file looks like this:

```
ID     SIZE    SPEED    RANK
123     10      20       2
567     15      30       1
890     10      20       2
321     20      10       3
295     15      30       1
```

The basic outline for the python module looks like this:

```
FAMILIES = {}
ATTRIBUTES = ['ID', 'SIZE', 'SPEED', 'RANK']
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as f:
  data = csv.DictReader(f)
  for row in data:
    fam_id = str(tuple([row[field_name] for field_name in ATTRIBUTES]))
    id = row['ID']
    FAMILIES.setdefault(fam_id, [])
    FAMILIES[fam_id].append(id)

output = []
for fam_id, node_arr in FAMILIES.items():
    for from_item in node_arr:
        for to_item in node_arr:
            if from_item != to_item:
                output.append(fam_id, from_item, to_item)

def write_array_to_csv(arr):
    with open('hdd_output_temp.csv', 'wb') as w:
        writer = csv.writer(w)
        writer.writerows(arr)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    write_array_to_csv(output)
```

Which would print into a CSV like this:

```
('10,20,2')    123    890
('10,20,2')    890    123
('15,30,1')    567    295
('15,30,1')    295    567
```

Now, my question is, if I were to go into the original csv file and make some revisions, how could I alter the code to detect all the updated relationships. I would like to put all the added relationships into FAMILIES2 and all the broken relationships into FAMILIES3. So if a new ID '589' were added that matched the '20,10,3' family and '890' was updated to have a different ID of '10,20,1',
I would like FAMILIES 2 to be able to output:

```
('20,10,3')    321    589
('20,10,3')    589    321
```

And FAMILIES3 to output:

```
('10,20,2')    123    890
('10,20,2')    890    123
```

Comment: Your current code doesn't work, and even if fixed, wouldn't "print into a CSV" what you show in your question. One major thing that is wrong is that the key values for the `FAMILIES` dictionary are tuples of _all_ the fields in each row and the value associated with it is what was in `row['ID']`. I think you should fix this and the other things wrong before asking us to help you accomplish the other things you want done.